# Rails 4.2.5 Mailer URL issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have currently set up a mailer which is notifying users that their invoice is ready.

The mailer is working correctly except the URL is adding a . instead of a slash in the url. For example - I am receiving the following which isn't directing to the intended link:

**www.mydomain.com/invoices.14**

Instead I would like it to say:

**www.mydomain.com/invoices/14**

My Set up is as follows:

**invoice_mailer.rb**

```
default_url_options[:host] = 'mydomain.com'
```

**invoice_mailer/invoice_ready.html.erb**

```
<p>Click the following link <strong><%= link_to @invoice.inv_num, invoices_url(@invoice) %></strong></p>
```

I'm not sure why but the redirection keeps adding the . in the URL. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a singular version of url helper:

```
<p>Click the following link <strong><%= link_to @invoice.inv_num, invoice_url(@invoice) %></strong></p>
```

Here is an example how it's works for instance `resources :invoices`

- `invoices_path` returns `/invoices` # *that's why you have `invoices.14`*
- `new_invoice_path` returns `/invoices/new`
- `edit_invoice_path(:id)` returns `/invoices/:id/edit` (for instance,
  `edit_invoice_path(10)` returns `/invoices/10/edit`)
- `invoice_path(:id)` returns `/invoices/:id` (for instance, `invoice_path(10)`
  returns`/invoices/10`)

> Each of these helpers has a corresponding `_url` helper (such as
>   `invoices_url`) which returns the same path prefixed with the current
>   host, port and path prefix.

[`Read the documentation CRUD, Verbs, and Actions`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)